# Elasticsearch DSL: filter, then aggregate in python

Tags: python-2.7, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I need to filter documents in an `Elasticsearch` index and then aggregate them by field. Here is the code of what I am trying to do:

```
import elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search, Q, Index, MultiSearch
es_client = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch([url],
        timeout=30, retry_on_timeout=True)
project_ids=['CSI'] 
family_ids=['SF6140691_WES_CIDR'] 
sample_ids=['S1379354_CIDR'] 
gene_symbols=['GLTPD1', 'CCNL2', 'MRPL20'] 

genes_filter = Q('bool', must=[Q('terms', project_id=project_ids),
                                   Q('terms', family_id=family_ids),
                                   Q('terms', sample_id=sample_ids),
                                   Q('terms', gene_symbol=gene_symbols)])
search = Search(using=es_client, index="GENES_DATA")
search = search.filter(genes_filter).execute()
results = search.aggs.bucket('by_family', 'terms', field='family_id', size=0)
```

Currently I am getting the following error:

> '{!r} object has no attribute {!r}'.format(self.**class**.**name**, name))
>   AttributeError: 'Terms' object has no attribute 'execute'

I tried to switch filtering and aggregation, tried doing `execute()` at the very end, but it does not help. How could this simple transformation be achieved - `filtering + aggregation`? I found examples of doing aggregations separately or filtering separately but have trouble finding both in one query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

```
search = search.filter(genes_filter)
results = search.aggs.bucket('by_family', 'terms', field='family_id', size=0)
```

you should have:

```
search = search.filter(genes_filter)
search.aggs.bucket('by_family', 'terms', field='family_id', size=0)
results = search.execute()
```

First you add a filter, then you define the aggregations and finally you execute your search.

Comment: The issue is that the buckets give me only the family name and count of the documents found, but not the whole object. Is there a way to get the following result because that is what I need: [{family_id_1: [doc_1, doc_2, ...]}, {family_id_2: [doc_8, doc_9, ...]}? I need a regular `group_by`, not just count of documents

Comment: Regular group by also doesn't give you rows, just the value you grouped by and potentially any aggregation functions you decide. If you want to retrieve the documents in the buckets use the `top_hits` aggregation - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html